# Null result from tibco webservice call in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, wsdl, tibco

I took the wsdl file given by a tibco web service and I put it in my project, after that I created the web reference giving to vs 2005 (yes I'm working on a legacy project) that wsdl file. VS 2005 generated the proxy and I used it in my vb.net code.

When I call the method exposed by the proxy I always get a null result. If I call the service with soapUI it give a correct response with expected data. How this is possible? The wsdl is given by the tibco service itself how can vs 2005 misunderstand the result of the call?

Many thanks in advance for any answer.

My vb code is:

```
Dim EvalError As Company.FrontEnd.Agents.Ws_EvaluateAgency.tnsERRORAlpha
Dim EvaluateOutput() As Company.FrontEnd.Agents.Ws_EvaluateAgency.tnsPNREvaluate

EvaluateInput.EvaluationOption.EvaluatorOption.ElaborationMode = FrontEnd.Agents.Ws_EvaluateAgency.tnsTypeOfElaboration.AutopilotAgy  '' Fase III
EvalError = ws_Valutazione.AgencyEvaluate(EvaluateInput, EvaluateOutput)
```

The input object have correct data. The output object is defined an so the EvalError

SOLVED: Was missing namespace specification in wsdl:input and wsdl:output tag  of the wsdl

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Hi i'm not at office yet, do you mean the wsdl or the vb code or both? As soon as possible i'll post the  code. Thank you

Comment: vb code, also have you checked the code while debugging to make any parameters have value - if applicable for the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Was missing namespace specification in wsdl:input and wsdl:output tag of the wsdl
For an unknown (for me) reason you MUST set namespace="http://InputMessageNamespace" in wsdl:input and namespace="http://OutputMessageNamespace" in wsdl:output